# I accidentally canceled a Send/Receive while downloading a large email. Is it gone forever?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

While downloading a large email, I clicked cancel and aborted the download.  It was taking way longer than it should because it was just a bunch of Excel attachments, so I thought I'd cancel, restart Outlook, and try again.  However, I am not getting anything now.  I know I can talk to the person who was sending that data and have them resend, but I could have also received other emails during that send/receive process.  Did I lose any emails that were coming through?  Is there a way to query the mail server again and get them?

Comment: what kind of mail account is it?  Exchange, IMAP, POP3?

Comment: Before getting too concerned, ask the sender how many attachments there were to verify you received them all. When cancel is clicked, it often finishes the current download before stopping. It's possible it was finished or had finished and was hung until you clicked cancel.

Answer (score 0):

Log into your email account via website. Mail might be there depending on how you configured your outlook preferences.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried, but no luck.

Comment: It looks like you have outlook cofigured with POP3 which stands for Post Office Protocol version 3. When an e-mail is sent to your address, it is stored on the mail server until it is downloaded via your e-mail client (Outlook, Netscape mail, your mobile, etc.) using POP3. After the e-mail has been downloaded to your client, it is removed from the server altogether.